# jQuery causing 'missing' text in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Really weird issue I've come across now.

I'm using jQuery to make some 'widget' windows (drag & resize). They work beautifully in everything but IE (big surprise, right?). They also do everything they're supposed to in IE (drag, resize, dim on moving, return to proper opacity on release). However, in IE, when you 'let go' of the window the text 'disappears'. This isn't the traditional 'click drag over it and it's visible' bugs. Text goes completely transparent, taking on whatever colour is behind the 'window' at the time. It's more like 'cut out text shapes'.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Are there any fixes?

Comment: How about posting some code? I never experienced that.

Comment: At this point I'm not even sure what code I'd post. Like I said, every bit of it works properly in every browser, except the disappearing text in IE. I can't pinpoint any place in particular. I've attempted to change text colour on release - which works in Chrome and FF, but it's like the text is completely _gone_ in IE.

Comment: @conLo Try looking at it with firebug or googles developer tool. They will show you whats going in on with the js, the css the markup everything.

Comment: One other thing is do you see a little alert icon in the lower left corner of IE? Maybe ie does'nt like something.

Comment: I've checked it out with IE's Developer Tools. It can't find a single error in my code either. I just ran it five times in a row to make sure, in fact.

Comment: How about you provide a link to this site?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved elsewhere. It was an opacity issue after all.