# dynamicpage.js causing odd text display behavior in IE only

Tags: jquery, text

When using dynamicpages.js to swap contents of a div, any new text contained within that div will flicker visible before "disappearing", meaning it remains on the page but only becomes visible again by click-dragging over it. This is only true on IE (at least it's true on IE8).

Even when the new  content is only text and nothing more complicated, this is true.

Efforts I've made to correct the problem based on online searching for a solution:

1) adding width and relative positioning to the offending div

2) clearing CSS attributes

3) no error message from IE when page is running; no errors in HTML-Kit (other than not recognizing  tag but I don't think that's relevant)

As a possibly helpful clue, I can get the text to remain visible if I insert an alert into a .livequery() call that listens for new 's. But when I close the alert, the text "disappears".

I will include any code you might think helpful but at this point, I can replicate the problem simply by linking to a new page with just text within a [div id="guts"] tag [since dynamicpage.js works with some hashtag program to intercept the new page request and, instead, swap out the contents of "guts".

But I'm a real noobie, here, so I will gladly comply with any and all requests for more information.

I've tried my best to find an answer in previous posts, especially since I saw [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508857/jquery-causing-missing-text-in-ie) that references the behavior in passing as being common. But couldn't find anything else right on topic.

Thanks!

-- Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Okay, like in so many instances in life, the moment you reach out for help after hours of painful inner-searching, the answer becomes obvious to you! The problem was in my CSS for the div tag.